# How to Grab an image file from Parse

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

So i've tried looking over the documentation and cant make heads or tails of it... so i'm hoping someone here can help:

so i've created a ParseFile with an image stored in a byte[]. I've saved this parsefile and then assigned it into a parseObject. I have then saved the parseObject

```
    profilePicFile = new ParseFile( "profilePic.png", bytes);
    Task saveProfilePic = profilePicFile.SaveAsync();
    yield return saveProfilePic;

    user["Profile_Pic"] = profilePicFile;
    Task updateUser = user.SaveAsync();
```

Then i've made a temporary button just to  check that this works. I've assigned it a new script. Basically when I hit the button, I just want it to grab the user, and its profile_pic and tell me if there is something there.

```
ParseObject receivedUser = new ParseObject("ReceivedUser");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("User");
    query.GetAsync("DwRfTQ66tA").ContinueWith(t =>
                                              {
         receivedUser = t.Result;
    });

    if (receivedUser.IsDataAvailable == true) {
        print ("getting data");
        byte[] data = receivedUser.Get<byte[]> ("Profile_Pic");

    } else {
        print ("no user");
    }
}
```

Am I doing this right? Do i need to re-initialise anything? Do I need to add the other script component to this or use Getcomponent to get the user data? (I dont think so since the ParseUser object is supposed to be a static right?). Or does this script need to re-log in to grab data from Parse?

currently the error i'm getting is KeyNotFoundException.

I deff have a User Class on parse and a Profile_Pic column. I'm using the object ID as the reference. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ParseObject.GetQuery("User")
```

you should be using:

```
ParseUser.Query
```